# Axios with react native not returning document and crashes app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, react-native, axios

## Edit

Ok, so my method was just fine. For some reason, when I changed `const response = await...` to `const res = await..` (or any other name besides "response" for that matter), it worked.. If this isn't a memory leak, then I have no idea what the heck this could have been. If anyone has any insight, I'd appreciate it.

---

I am making a request from my client:

```
const config = { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } };

const data = JSON.stringify({ postId });

console.log('sending request'); // prints

const response = await axios.post(
  `http://${GATEWAY}:5000/api/posts/single`,
  data,
  config
);

console.log("response received"); // never reached
```

But `request received` is never printed.

My backend route has this,

```
const post = await Post.findById(postId).populate("likes");

console.log(post); // prints post

return res.json(post);
```

And it appropriately find the post and logs it to the console. I'm not sure what's going on. No errors are printed anywhere and the app crashes after some time. It's probably waiting for the response.

Also, when I do

`return res.json(null)`

my client receives the response. But when I try to return the `post` or even if I try to

`return res.json( { msg: "Hello World" } );`

it hangs.

In addition, I do similar axios requests throughout the app -- they work and behave as expected. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

I've even tried,

```
const response = await axios.get(
  `http://${GATEWAY}:5000/api/posts/${postId}`,
);
```

But it behaves and fails in the same way. If I let the request hang for too long, the app just gives up and crashes.

Note, also, I'm using `axios` instead of `axios-react-native`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure it is **"http"** not **"https"**
**or**
else try:

```
const url = `${apiBaseUrl}/someUrlText/someUrlText/`;
const headers = {headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"}};
const body = JSON.stringify({ postId });
axios
.post(url, body, headers)
.then(res => {
  console.log("request received",res);
})
.catch(err => console.log("TODO: Handle error axios", err));
```

Comment: which one did you use the first suggestion or second @MikeK?

Comment: The second suggestion. BUT I also just tested with `const reponse = await axios.post(url, body, headers); console.log("request received", reponse.data);` and it worked as well.. what was I doing wrong?